# Is there a command line switch to specify the video resolution for DirectQ (a Quake 1 source port)

Tags: quake

I have tried `directq.exe -width x -height y` which works with some other source ports but not this one. At startup it always defaults to 800x600.

Does anyone know if there is a command line option that works with DirectQ?

Answer (score -1):

Some versions need the color mode as well I think. So try this:

```
-width 1920 -height 1080 -bpp 32
```

Where -bpp is either `16` or `32` for 16 bit color, and 32 bit.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. In this case it did not work.